# Trainer is not attached to model

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I am using pytorch lightning to train a model. I want to log the performance metric, and I am using the following code in the `validation_epoch_end()` to do that:

```
def validation_epoch_end(self, outputs) -> None:
    super().__init__()
    mean_loss = torch.mean(torch.stack([o["Val_Loss"] for o in outputs]))
    mean_rocauc = np.mean(np.array([o["Score"] for o in outputs]))
  
    self.log("val_loss",mean_loss,on_epoch=True,prog_bar=True)
    self.log("val_score",mean_rocauc,on_epoch=True,prog_bar=True)
```

Now I fit the model to trainer using the following code:

```
trainer = pl.Trainer(max_epochs=2,accelerator="gpu",devices=1)
trainer.fit(model=model,train_dataloaders=train_dataloader,val_dataloaders=dev_dataloader)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
RuntimeError: MemeNet is not attached to a `Trainer`.
```

Note that MemeNet is the name of my model. For some reason logging is failing but I don't know why.

Comment: I don't think you are supposed to have this line `super().__init__()`. It's for __init__ function of your model